# Office Outlook Add-In OAuth Error

Tags: rest, oauth, outlook, office365

i'm currently developing an Office Outlook App.
I'm trying to get the messages (specially the Attachments of messages)
from the Exchange Server.
I'm using the Outlook Desktop Application.

I already got the **bearer** authentication token and i'm trying using the **Office REST-API** to get the messages, but there is a strange error if i send the GET request to the server.

Error:
"**The api you are trying to access does not support item scoped OAuth.**"

Here is my JavaScript-Code:

```
        Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync(function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status === "succeeded") {
            var authToken = asyncResult.value;
            var attUrl = 'https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages/';
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: attUrl,
                beforeSend: function (request) {
                    request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/*, application/xml, application/json; odata.metadata=none");
                    request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken);
                    request.setRequestHeader("X-AnchorMailbox", "test@test.de");
                },
                success: function (responseData) {
                    console.log("success", responseData);
                },
                error: function (errData) {
                    console.log("err", errData);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I'm scanning the outgoing traffic and there seems everything ok:

GET outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages/ HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer TokenIsCorrect

Accept: text/*, application/xml, application/json; odata.metadata=none

X-AnchorMailbox: test@test.de

Referer: localhost:44300/AddInRead/App/Index/Index.html

Accept-Language: de-DE

Origin: localhost:44300

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko

Host: outlook.office.com

DNT: 1

Connection: Keep-Alive

Cache-Control: no-cache

.................

I refered to:
**Outlook Mail REST-API Reference**

and the samples on
**Outlook Dev Center OAuth Sandbox**

I think i searched the hole internet, but couldn't find anything
to fix this problem.

Hopefully someone can give me the right hint.

BTW: had to remove some links cause of no reputation of my account :/

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and i was able to fix it.

There is a difference between the Access-Token and the Token you get, if you call the **Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync** function of the REST-API.
I could see that with logging-in in Outlook Dev Center OAuth Sandbox with my own account, get the token and compare this token with the token i get in VS with getCallbackTokenAsync.

They are different.
The Token from the function is only for getting attachments or items.
In this case i thought "items" are messages and i could start a request for all messages with that token, but wrong.
You have to take the token from the function and address the attachment directly with
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages/' + idMail + '/attachments/' + mail.attachments[i].id;

Best regards